# Recycler view not showing one card view in android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display an array list in the card view of a fragment through recycler view. The array list contains five values to be displayed on the five card views of a fragment. But it is displaying only four.The code for fragment is written below:

```
public class AddMemberFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private View view ;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String userId;
String n_team ;
private ArrayList<Friend> friends;


public AddMemberFragment() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addnewfriend_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    userId = firebaseUser.getUid();
    ManageTeamTabbedActivity activity = (ManageTeamTabbedActivity) getActivity();
    n_team = activity.getMyData();
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.addNewFriend);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    mRootRef.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<Friend> friendArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("demo", "USERID " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                Friend friend = new Friend();
                friend.setId(userSnapshot.getKey());
                friend.setFriendName((String) userSnapshot.child("profiles").child("fname").getValue());  //Implement it
                friendArrayList.add(friend);
            }
            friends = friendArrayList;
            mAdapter = new AddFriendAdapter(getActivity(), friends, n_team);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

The adapter code is written below.

```
public class AddFriendAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddFriendAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<Friend> mData;
private Context mContext;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private String u_team ;

public AddFriendAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Friend> friendList , String u_team) {
    this.mData = friendList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.u_team= u_team;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.addnewfriend_layout, parent, false);
    AddFriendAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = new AddFriendAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Friend frnd =(Friend) mData.get(position);

    holder.friendName.setText(frnd.getFriendName());
    holder.addFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            frnd.setStatus("sent");
            final DatabaseReference mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            final String UID = firebaseUser.getUid();
            mRootRef.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    mRootRef.child("users").child(UID).child("Your Teams").child("requests").child(frnd.getId()).setValue(frnd);
                    Friend temp = new Friend();
                    temp.setId(firebaseUser.getUid());
                    temp.setFriendName(firebaseUser.getDisplayName());
                    temp.setStatus("received");
                    mRootRef.child("users").child(frnd.getId()).child("Your Teams ").child("requests").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(temp);
                    mData.remove(frnd);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override

                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView friendName;
    ImageButton addFriend;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        friendName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewFriendName);
        addFriend = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagebuttonFriendAdd);
    }
}
```

The screenshot of emulator is also attached, in which there are four card views in ADD NEW MEMBER fragment.

[image]

I tired to debug it myself and found that the entries in the array list are five as expected. [image]

Database picture is also attached for reference.As shown in the picture, it has also five IDs to be displayed but the recycler view is displaying four.[image]

Comment: What does Android show when you print out your ArrayList?

Comment: I printed it through Log.d() inside onBindViewHolder and got the correct number of values.I also added 6th record. And the six values are shown in the array list quite rightly.Something might have not been working while printing this array list using card views.

Comment: Isn't this line `mData.remove(frnd);` cause you that behavior?

Comment: I commented that still the problem was not resolved. So I don't think if it's causing this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put my comment in answer field because of this restriction: 'You must have 50 reputation to comment'.

How about putting `Log.d()` inside `onBindViewHolder` to monitor the values?
Using 'breakpoints' to analyse data at `onActivityCreated()` is not a great idea as the UI might have not been fully populated yet. Also, you might as well add a 6th record, does it show 4 or 5 records? In that way, you can find out whether it is a last record issue or something else.

Comment: I printed it through Log.d() inside onBindViewHolder and got the correct number of values.I also added 6th record. And the six values are shown in the array list quite rightly.Something might have not been working while printing this array list using card views.